# React - Changes made to CSS in a function doesn't update on localhost without refresh

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So I have this useState which obtains the initial state from a function.

```
export default function App() {
  const [isTextCopied, setIsTextCopied] = useState(() => getDefaultCopyBtnText()) // This doesn't work
```

Here's the function:

```
  function getDefaultCopyBtnText() {
    return (<>
      <span>Copy</span>
      <FontAwesomeIcon className='ml-2 text-xs xs:text-md text-orange-400' icon={faCopy} />
    </>)
  }
```

The state `isTextCopied` is rendered in a button like below:

```
<button ref={copyBtnRef} className='hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 py-2 sm:px-4 sm:py-2 rounded bg-gray-800 font- semibold' onClick={copyExcuse}>
     {isTextCopied}
</button>
```

The changes I make in the rest of the code update instantly on my localhost. However, the changes I make in `getDefaultCopyBtnText()` i.e, `xs:text-sm` changed to `xs:textmd` `or` `<span>Copy</span>` changed to `<span>srdtfg</span>` triggers hot reload but I still have to refresh manually to see the changes in the button.

Also, if I set the initial state on component mount even though I have the same function being used to initialise the `useState`, it works fine!

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    setIsTextCopied(getDefaultCopyBtnText()) // This works
  }, [])
```

How?
This has been really annoying.

1. I have tried reinstalling all the packages
2. Tried adding import React from 'react' on the of every `.tsx` file.
3. Tried clearing the browser cache and used Incognito mode.
4. Even tried different machines.

Nothing seems to help

Comment: Try changing `useState(() => getDefaultCopyBtnText())` to `useState(getDefaultCopyBtnText())`

Comment: I tried. It didn't work though. There must be some problem with my understanding of how the state is initialised and updated upon rerenders.

Comment: As I see in your code getDefaultCopyBtnText() method is only used in useEffect but when you perform any kind of event and you want to change it that means getDefaultCopyBtnText() used again to do that but couldn't see this method again in anywhere in your code